# Removing a value from ConcurrentDictionary<key, List<value>>

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

I'm writing a (hopefully) thread-safe data structure, which is essentially a wrapper around a ConcurrentDictionary of HashSets.

What I would like to do is to have a few methods like this:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<K, HashSet<V>> _index = new ConcurrentDictionary<K, HashSet<V>>();

public void Remove(V value)
{
    // Remove all instances of value from _index
}

public void Remove(K key, V value)
{
    // Remove value from _index[key]
}
```

I was hoping that something similar to ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate(key, newValue, Func) would exist for TryRemove, but no luck. Both of these Remove methods are pretty easy to write for a regular dictionary, but when it comes to concurrentizing them, I'm at a loss. Someone point me in the right direction? :)

Comment: *Remove all instances of value from _index[key]* makes no sense. Hashset can contain only unique elements. For your question, you definitely need a lock over hashset while removing elements.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes but the dictionary contains multiple HashSets, each with possibly one item.

Comment: @jtimperley My comment is applicable only for second method, which makes no sense as it takes `Key` as parameter in which case there is only one hashset hence only one item.

Comment: [What is this thing you call "thread safe"?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx)

Comment: Edited the comment. I originally wrote it using a List<V>.

Comment: Your first method might be quite inefficient if your dictionary is large

Comment: Your primary problem is that whereas the `ConcurrentDictionary` can be safely modified by multiple threads, the values it holds are not necessarily thread-safe. So you need some kind of synchronization on the values. In this case, on the `HashSet<T>` that you're modifying. Even `Remove(K key, V value)` needs some kind of mutual exclusion on the `HashSet` to prevent concurrent modification.

Comment: Would this be more efficiently implemented by encapsulating a `ConcurrentDictionary<KeyValuePair<K, V>, byte>` where `byte` is just a dummy value?

Comment: It looks like the best way forward is to lock HashSet<V> when removing elements from it, then (or perhaps use ConcurrentBag?)